# Restore a running application from batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd

I have a Windows Photo viewer opened and minimized.
How do I restore it to the foreground from a batch program?
I figured out that the application is "dllhost.exe"

I tried this command:

```
    START /MAX dllhost.exe
```

I also tried to kill the application and start all over again but doesn't help.

PS: I have a IE running in the foreground.

Any solutions?

Comment: `DLLHost.exe` is not a runnable application. See [What is dllhost.exe](http://www.neuber.com/taskmanager/process/dllhost.exe.html). It's used to host other executable code provided in DCOM DLLs (in other words, it's a loader for hosting other code including the .NET runtime, and many copies of it at the same time can be running hosting different things). Your /MAX is doing nothing here.

Comment: A better link: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081030002731AATB5Z7 - see the two answers, not the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything in the CMD DOS language that will do what you are asking.  However, you might be able to accomplish what you want using VBScript, if the application has a unique name in its title-bar.

### Test.vbs

```
set s = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

s.AppActivate "Calculator"
wscript.sleep(100)
s.SendKeys("% r")
```

This script will find the `Calculator` and activate it, sleep for 100 milliseconds , and then press alt+space (to activate the system menu) and then press `r`, which will `restore` the application.

Note: `Calculator` must already be running -- it will not launch it if it is not...